# Hibernate shows database password in log file

Tags: hibernate, passwords, jetty

I am running Hibernate in a web server application, using Jetty web server and servlet engine. Hibernate is initialised via hibernate.properties. Upon initialisation, the following appears in the log file:

```
Mar 13, 2017 6:58:56 AM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.7.Final}
Mar 13, 2017 6:58:56 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.c3p0.timeout=500, javax.persistence.jdbc.user=sa, hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=50, hibernate.c3p0.max_size=20, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=2000, javax.persistence.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE, hibernate.format_sql=true, javax.persistence.jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver, hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.show_sql=true, javax.persistence.jdbc.password=sa}
```

Note the `javax.persistence.jdbc.password=sa` at the end of the last line. I don't want my database password to appear in a log file as it is a security risk. The C3P0 connection pool service, for instance, is more benign:

```
Mar 13, 2017 6:58:56 AM org.hibernate.c3p0.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider configure
INFO: HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
```

Is there a way to stop Hibernate logging the full contents of the properties file at the start? I don't want to change the overall logging level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code in Hibernate 5.0.11 in `org.hibernate.cfg.Environment` (line 198) Hibernate will already mask the value of `hibernate.connection.password` if it is set.

However it looks like you're setting the value `javax.persistence.jdbc.password`. If you switch to using `hibernate.connection.password` this should work.

Comment: Your suggestion looks like it should work, except for the fact that I'm using the same javax.persistence properties for some other database setup in my testing, so would prefer not to change. As it happens, because I use these properties in more than one place I was already loading them myself and configuring Hibernate programatically. It was an oversight on my part that I had kept the file name as hibernate.properties and Hibernate was opening it independently of my own configuration code. I just renamed the property file and now Hibernate knows nothing about it.